# How to get COUNT DISTINCT in translated SQL with EF Core

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.1

I want to have EF core translate `.Select(x=>x.property).Distinct().Count()` into something like

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT property)
```

Let's take an example. Let's say I have a DB table with PersonID(long), VisitStart(datetime2) and VisitEnd(datetime2).
If i want to get the number of distinct days a particular person has visited, then I could write SQL like

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(date, VisitStart)) FROM myTable GROUP BY PersonID
```

But using EF core and this

```
MyTable
    .GroupBy(x=>x.PersonID)
    .Select(x=> new 
    {
        Count = x.Select(y=>y.VisitStart.Date).Distinct().Count()
    })
```

which gives the right results, translates into this SQL

```
SELECT [x].[PersonID], [x].[VisitStart], [x].[VisitEnd]
FROM [myTable] as [x]
ORDER BY [x].[PersonID]
```

There is no GROUP BY and no DISTINCT or COUNT anywhere so the grouping must be done in memory, which is not ideal when operating on a table that has millions of records that potentially has to be pulled from DB.

So anyone know how to get EF core to translate a `.Select(...).Distinct().Count()` into `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`

Comment: Which EF Core version? It's quite possible this isn't implemented yet.

Comment: a part of me needs to know... if you know what the SQL is that you want to run, why not just *run that SQL*? that a: gives you exactly what you want, and b: avoids the overhead of runtime processing of expression tress and SQL generation; EF/EF-core has APIs for running raw SQL, no? Or tools like dapper?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's EF Core 2.1

Comment: Im slightly sketical that the LINQ you posted generates the SQL you posted - your LINQ does not mention `VisitEnd` at all, yet its in the SQL generated?? Are you sure youve picked out the right SQL from a (presumed) trace of the DB? Or are you saying it just loads the entire table into memory?

Comment: @MarcGravell You're right that I could just use the raw SQL. The main reason that i don't want to use raw SQL is that it kinda undermines the reason to use EF Core in the first place, and then I'm left with hardcoded SQL strings. Also I'm simply curious why It's not working as expected.

Comment: @Jamiec It's an example adapted from my real table, but yes all the columns are included in the select, which also seems weird to me.

Comment: And you never *really* materialize the table  `MyTable.ToList()` or equivalent. Its never helpful when you adapt real code to "I think this is equivalent" as often you mask the *real* problem.

Comment: @Jamiec You're right, and I've just tried to created the actual table and columns according to my description and tried the linq query. The resulting SQL is exactly as described above

Comment: EF never supported (and still doesn't) `COUNT(DISTINCT expr)` SQL construct. EF Core allows you to map custom scalar functions, but not custom aggregate functions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update (EF Core 5.x):**

Starting with version 5.0, expression `Select(expr).Distinct().Count()` is now recognized by EF Core and translated to the corresponding SQL `COUNT(DISTINCT expr))`, hence the original LINQ query can be used w/o modification.

---

**Original (EF Core 2.x), the solution DOES NOT work with EF Core 3.x due to query pipeline rewrite:**

EF (6 and Core) historically does not support this standard SQL construct. Most likely because of the lack of standard LINQ method and technical difficulties of mapping `Select(expr).Distinct().Count()` to it.

The good thing is that EF Core is extendable by replacing many of its internal services with custom derived implementations to override the required behaviors. Not easy, requires a lot of plumbing code, but doable.

So the idea is to add and use simple custom `CountDistinct` methods like this

```
public static int CountDistinct<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector)
    => source.Select(keySelector).Distinct().Count();

public static int CountDistinct<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    => source.Select(keySelector).Distinct().Count();
```

and let EF Core somehow translate them to SQL. In fact EF Core provides a simple way of defining (and even custom translating) database scalar functions, but unfortunately this cannot be used for aggregate functions which have separate processing pipeline. So we need to dig deeply into EF Core infrastructure.

The full code for that for EF Core 2.x pipeline is provided at the end. Not sure if it's worth efforts because EF Core 3.0 will use complete rewritten query process pipeline. But it was interesting and also I'm pretty sure it can be updated for the new (hopefully simpler) pipeline.

Anyway, all you need is to copy/paste the code into a new code file in the project, add the following to the context `OnConfiguring` override

```
optionsBuilder.UseCustomExtensions();
```

which will plug the functionality into EF Core infrastructure, and then query like this

```
var result = db.MyTable
    .GroupBy(x => x.PersonID, x => new { VisitStartDate = x.VisitStart.Date })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Count = g.CountDistinct(x => x.VisitStartDate)
    }).ToList();
```

will luckily be translated to the desired

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(CONVERT(date, [x].[VisitStart]))) AS [Count]
FROM [MyTable] AS [x]
GROUP BY [x].[PersonID]
```

Note the preselecting the expression needed for aggregate method. This is current EF Core limitation/requirement for all aggregate methods, not just ours.

Finally, the full code that does the magic:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Expressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal;
using Remotion.Linq;
using Remotion.Linq.Clauses;
using Remotion.Linq.Clauses.ResultOperators;
using Remotion.Linq.Clauses.StreamedData;
using Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static partial class CustomExtensions
    {
        public static int CountDistinct<T, TKey>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector)
            => source.Select(keySelector).Distinct().Count();

        public static int CountDistinct<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
            => source.Select(keySelector).Distinct().Count();

        public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseCustomExtensions(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder
                .ReplaceService<INodeTypeProviderFactory, CustomNodeTypeProviderFactory>()
                .ReplaceService<IRelationalResultOperatorHandler, CustomRelationalResultOperatorHandler>();
    }
}

namespace Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel
{
    public sealed class CountDistinctExpressionNode : ResultOperatorExpressionNodeBase
    {
        public CountDistinctExpressionNode(MethodCallExpressionParseInfo parseInfo, LambdaExpression optionalSelector)
            : base(parseInfo, null, optionalSelector) { }
        public static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetSupportedMethods()
            => typeof(CustomExtensions).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethods("CountDistinct");
        public override Expression Resolve(ParameterExpression inputParameter, Expression expressionToBeResolved, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
            => throw CreateResolveNotSupportedException();
        protected override ResultOperatorBase CreateResultOperator(ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
            => new CountDistinctResultOperator();
    }
}

namespace Remotion.Linq.Clauses.ResultOperators
{
    public sealed class CountDistinctResultOperator : ValueFromSequenceResultOperatorBase
    {
        public override ResultOperatorBase Clone(CloneContext cloneContext) => new CountDistinctResultOperator();
        public override StreamedValue ExecuteInMemory<T>(StreamedSequence input) => throw new NotSupportedException();
        public override IStreamedDataInfo GetOutputDataInfo(IStreamedDataInfo inputInfo) => new StreamedScalarValueInfo(typeof(int));
        public override string ToString() => "CountDistinct()";
        public override void TransformExpressions(Func<Expression, Expression> transformation) { }
    }
}

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal
{
    public class CustomNodeTypeProviderFactory : DefaultMethodInfoBasedNodeTypeRegistryFactory
    {
        public CustomNodeTypeProviderFactory()
            => RegisterMethods(CountDistinctExpressionNode.GetSupportedMethods(), typeof(CountDistinctExpressionNode));
    }

    public class CustomRelationalResultOperatorHandler : RelationalResultOperatorHandler
    {
        private static readonly ISet<Type> AggregateResultOperators = (ISet<Type>)
            typeof(RequiresMaterializationExpressionVisitor).GetField("_aggregateResultOperators", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
            .GetValue(null);

        static CustomRelationalResultOperatorHandler()
            => AggregateResultOperators.Add(typeof(CountDistinctResultOperator));

        public CustomRelationalResultOperatorHandler(IModel model, ISqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory sqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory, ISelectExpressionFactory selectExpressionFactory, IResultOperatorHandler resultOperatorHandler)
            : base(model, sqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory, selectExpressionFactory, resultOperatorHandler)
        { }

        public override Expression HandleResultOperator(EntityQueryModelVisitor entityQueryModelVisitor, ResultOperatorBase resultOperator, QueryModel queryModel)
            => resultOperator is CountDistinctResultOperator ?
                HandleCountDistinct(entityQueryModelVisitor, resultOperator, queryModel) :
                base.HandleResultOperator(entityQueryModelVisitor, resultOperator, queryModel);

        private Expression HandleCountDistinct(EntityQueryModelVisitor entityQueryModelVisitor, ResultOperatorBase resultOperator, QueryModel queryModel)
        {
            var queryModelVisitor = (RelationalQueryModelVisitor)entityQueryModelVisitor;
            var selectExpression = queryModelVisitor.TryGetQuery(queryModel.MainFromClause);
            var inputType = queryModel.SelectClause.Selector.Type;
            if (CanEvalOnServer(queryModelVisitor)
                && selectExpression != null
                && selectExpression.Projection.Count == 1)
            {
                PrepareSelectExpressionForAggregate(selectExpression, queryModel);
                var expression = selectExpression.Projection[0];
                var subExpression = new SqlFunctionExpression(
                    "DISTINCT", inputType, new[] { expression.UnwrapAliasExpression() });
                selectExpression.SetProjectionExpression(new SqlFunctionExpression(
                    "COUNT", typeof(int), new[] { subExpression }));
                return new ResultTransformingExpressionVisitor<int>(
                    queryModelVisitor.QueryCompilationContext, false)
                    .Visit(queryModelVisitor.Expression);
            }
            else
            {
                queryModelVisitor.RequiresClientResultOperator = true;
                var typeArgs = new[] { inputType };
                var distinctCall = Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Enumerable), "Distinct", typeArgs,
                    queryModelVisitor.Expression);
                return Expression.Call(
                    typeof(Enumerable), "Count", typeArgs,
                    distinctCall);
            }
        }

        private static bool CanEvalOnServer(RelationalQueryModelVisitor queryModelVisitor) =>
            !queryModelVisitor.RequiresClientEval && !queryModelVisitor.RequiresClientSelectMany &&
            !queryModelVisitor.RequiresClientJoin && !queryModelVisitor.RequiresClientFilter &&
            !queryModelVisitor.RequiresClientOrderBy && !queryModelVisitor.RequiresClientResultOperator &&
            !queryModelVisitor.RequiresStreamingGroupResultOperator;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried adding your code to a new file, but get two errors. Can't find the `PrepareSelectExpressionForAggregate` and  `expression.UnwrapAliasExpression()` methods

Comment: If you are on 2.1, comment out the first line and replace the second with `(expression as AliasExpression)?.Expression ?? expression`. One of the problems with using internal code is that you have to update it with every release.

Comment: It's definitely worth the upgrade to EF5 for this feature.

Comment: Would be cool if the new `DistinctBy` was supported so we could do `x.DistinctBy(y => y.VisitStart.Date).Count()`

Comment: @benmccallum They are planning to do so - I think in EFC 7.0. But hey, at the time this was written, they don't even supported the original `Select` + `Distinct` + `Count`. If someone (or their customers) can wait EFC to implement some construct... SQL in that regard is much clear and concise than LINQ, even with the operator you mentioned - there you do simply `COUNT(DISTINCT table.column`) which can't be beaten :-)

Comment: Does not work in ef core 5 or 6 when using a group by

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to share an idea I had for solving my issues about count distinct.

Ultimately another way of doing count distinct in a group by function, is by having nested group by functions (assuming you can aggregate your data through).

Here is an example of what I used, it seems to work.

Apologes for the criptic acronims, I am using this to keep my JSON as small as can be.

```
var myData = _context.ActivityItems
                        .GroupBy(a => new { ndt = EF.Property<DateTime>(a, "dt").Date, ntn = a.tn })
                        .Select(g => new
                        {
                            g.Key.ndt,
                            g.Key.ntn,
                            dpv = g.Sum(o => o.pv),
                            dlv = g.Sum(o => o.lv),
                            cnt = g.Count(),
                        })
                        .GroupBy(a => new { ntn = a.ntn })
                        .Select(g => new
                        {
                            g.Key.ntn,
                            sd = g.Min(o => o.ndt),
                            ld = g.Max(o => o.ndt),
                            pSum = g.Sum(o => o.dpv),
                            pMin = g.Min(o => o.dpv),
                            pMax = g.Max(o => o.dpv),
                            pAvg = g.Average(o => o.dpv),
                            lSum = g.Sum(o => o.dlv),
                            lMin = g.Min(o => o.dlv),
                            lMax = g.Max(o => o.dlv),
                            lAvg = g.Average(o => o.dlv),
                            n10s = g.Sum(o => o.cnt),
                            ndays = g.Count()
                        });
```