# Optimizing queries in Entity Framework Core / LINQ for group by / count()

Tags: sql, .net, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have been trying out different ways to write queries that include "group by" and "count()" using Entity Framework Core and LINQ. But the SQL that is generated simply returns all records and then the "group by" and "count()" is done in memory.

Currently I am trying to write a query that is equivalent to the following SQL:

```
select 
    e.EngagementId,
    e.Name,
    c.ClientName,
    count(distinct ed.EngagementDocumentId) as DocumentCount,
    count(distinct es.EngagementSurveyId) as SurveyCount
from Engagement e
inner join Client c on c.ClientId = e.ClientId
left outer join EngagementDocument ed on ed.EngagementId = e.EngagementId
left outer join EngagementSurvey es on es.EngagementId = e.EngagementId
group by e.EngagementId, e.Name, c.ClientName
```

My question is: How can I write a query that generates similar SQL?

Comment: What EF Core version are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.2.4

Comment: See [How to get COUNT DISTINCT in translated SQL with EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803706/how-to-get-count-distinct-in-translated-sql-with-ef-core/56831483#56831483)

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look. But my problem isn't particularly with "count distinct". Generally all queries using "group by" seem to be handled in memory. I just used the example above because if I can solve that then I will be able to solve simpler queries using "group by" also.

Comment: Please include a Minimal, Reproducible Example including model classes. In general I would recommend to use navigation properties on your model (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships) and avoid writing query syntax linq in favor of method syntax linq. This will give a more natural flow to the queries and it's easier to see where linq to entities fails to translate to sql.

Comment: If after `GroupBy` you add `Select` with only key / aggregates, the query should be translated to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend correlated subqueries or (equivalently) lateral joins:

```
select e.EngagementId, e.Name, c.ClientName,
       (select count(*)
        from EngagementDocument ed 
        where ed.EngagementId = e.EngagementId,
       ) as DocumentCount,
       (select count(*)
        from EngagementSurvey es 
        where es.EngagementId = e.EngagementId,
       ) as SurveyCount
from Engagement e inner join
     Client c 
     on c.ClientId = e.ClientId;
```

In addition, your want indexes on `EngagementDocument(EngagementId)` and `EngagementSurvey(EngagementId)`.

Your version is creating a Cartesian product of documents and surveys for each client/engagement -- and then using additional resources to aggregate and remove duplicates.  The above can just do the counts by scanning the indexes.

Comment: Interesting! I was under the impression that using joins and "group by" achieves better performance than using subqueries?! And that subqueries should generally be avoided. Anyway, how would this translate to EF / LINQ?