# How to count distinct

Tags: linq

I'm implementing ASP.NET Core project and have a query like the following for finding count of distinct `userId` per `operatorName`, however it shows me error for the line count distinct after running the project:

```cs
var activeUserPerOperatorCount = requests.GroupBy(x => new { operatorName = x.Operator.Name, x.UserId }).Select(x => new
    {
        userIds = x.Key.UserId,
        operatorNames = x.Key.operatorName,
        activeUserPerOperatorCount = x.Select(l => l.UserId).Distinct().Count()
    }).ToList();
```

I appreciate if anyone helps me how can I find distinct count of `userId` per `operatorName` in my query.

Comment: follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56831483/6797509

Answer (score 0):

ok, the correct query is like the following and it works correctly:

```
  var activeUserPerOperatorCount = requests.GroupBy(x => new { operatorName = x.Operator.Name}).Select(x => new
            {
                operatorNames = x.Key.operatorName,
                activeUserPerOperatorCount = requests.Select(l => l.UserId).Distinct().Count()

            }).ToList();
```