# Is there a way to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in EF Core 3.1?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a table with the following data

```
ID  DateColumn Amount
1   2021-01-25  50
2   2021-01-24  10
1   2021-01-25  100
```

I need the following output,

```
ID  DayCount    TotalAmount
1     1            150
2     1            10
```

I'm trying to lambda expression that would generate the following SQL query,

```
select ID, Count(distinct DateColumn) as DayCount, Sum(Amount) as TotalAmount 
from test 
group by id
```

I've writte the following expression,

```
            return await _context.Tests
                .GroupBy(g => g.id)
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    Data = s.Key,
                    Count = s.Select(t => t.DateColumn).Distinct().Count()
                }).ToListAsync();
```

and it throws the InValidOperation exception.

Comment: `Select(expr).Distinct().Count()` works only in EF Core 5+

Comment: Thank you. Just found the following, https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17376

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve what I'm trying to do in EF Core 3.1?

Comment: Not without a lot of work [as shown in this almost-duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803706/how-to-get-count-distinct-in-translated-sql-with-ef-core). It's probably easier to upgrade to EF Core 5. There are no significant [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/breaking-changes) unless you target .NET Old (Framework)

Comment: Thank you. I'd have to find out if we are targeting .Net framework. But yes it looks much easier to just upgrade to EF Core 5

Answer (score 0):

1. There seems to be an error in the resulting table for the first record, which should have a value of 2 for the DayCount.
2. The resting table construction looks like it could use some rearchitecting due to the Id column containing duplicates.

Regardless of structure, you can use an inner GROUP BY to achieve similar results:

```
return await _context.Tests
    .GroupBy(g => g.id)
    .Select(s => new
    {
        Data = s.Key,
        Count = s.GroupBy(t => t.DateColumn).Select(g => g.key).Count()
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: EF Core 3.1 can't translate this, fyi.