# How can I get users group it by time in IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, iqueryable, ef-core-3.1

I have this query

```
var creature = await _context.Data
                             .Where(x => x.Id.Contains("mono"))
                             .GroupBy(group => new
                                               {   
                                                    month = group.Time.Month,
                                                    year = group.Time.Year,
                                               })
                             .Select(data => new 
                                             {
                                                 data.Key.month,
                                                 data.Key.year,
                                                 User = data.Select(x => x.User.Distinct().Count())
                                             })
                             .ToListAsync()
```

I need to take the number of the users distinctly and group them by the month and the year.

But I get an error that the query is not readable and cannot translate it!

What should I modify here?

Comment: What is the underlying data store here? is it an RDBMS (i.e. a database)? If so: honestly, the moment LINQ starts fighting you: just write SQL - it will be easier to maintain, give you the right result *and* it will be more efficient (a: because there's no query comprehension step, and b: because hand-written SQL is usually *much* better than machine-generated SQL)

Comment: Which version of EF Core do you use? I know how to write such query only for 5+

Comment: EF is 3.1 and the data from database

Comment: This technically is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803706/how-to-get-count-distinct-in-translated-sql-with-ef-core/56831483#56831483. Unfortunately the solution there does not work for v3.x, and I have no time for updating it, and does it worth at all since it's already implemented in 5.x. So may be good time for upgrading? As soon as you don't use NET Framework, it shouldn't be a problem (compared for instance with 2.x to 3.x due to the lot of breaking changes).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, sometimes the best way to write an `IQueryable<T>` expression is: not to; it *looks like* `_context` here is a DB-context, most like Entity Framework. If so: just use SQL (the exact API for this depends on your EF version, and/or whether you're happy to use something like Dapper instead, which can be useful when the query doesn't need any ORM input); the SQL is going to be something like:

```sql
select  DATEPART(year, yt.Time) as [Year],
        DATEPART(month, yt.Time) as [Month],
        COUNT(DISTINCT yt.UserId) as [Users]
from YourTable yt
where yt.Id like '%mono%'
group by DATEPART(year, yt.Time), DATEPART(month, yt.Time)
order by DATEPART(year, yt.Time), DATEPART(month, yt.Time);
```